# *in* keyword with String in Groovy

Tags: groovy

```
groovy:000> 'hello' in 'hello world'
===> false
groovy:000> 'hello world'.contains('hello')
===> true
groovy:000> 'hello' in ['hello', 'world']
===> true
groovy:000> ['hello', 'world'].contains('hello')
===> true
```

Now, shouldn't the `in` keyword imitate `contains` for `String` like it does for `List`? Is it a bug or is it how it's supposed to be? I am using Groovy 2.3.7.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your situation but FYI... `'hello world' in ~/hello.*/` should evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown but `"Hello" in ~/Hello.+/` does not.

Comment: @smac89 Agreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` keyword works on `Collection` types; not on `String` types.

**Why does `String` to `String` Comparison work?**

Groovy `in` operator depends on the `isCase` method. It will use that in comparison. The `String` `isCase` method uses `equals` to perform this comparison. Obviously `hello` is not equal to `hello world`, ergo it returns `false`. However, `hello` does equal `hello`, ergo `true`.

Comment: But shouldn't it? `'hello' in 'hello'` gives `true`.

Comment: So my guess is, it depends on `contains` for all classes implementing `Collection`. So why depend on `isCase` for `String`? When we use the `in` keyword what is should mean is whether the the object on the right *is present in* the object in the left, shouldn't it?

Comment: It does not depend on `contains` for all classes implementing `Collection`. It depends on `isCase`, which just happens to use `contains` for its comparison. That is just how they chose to go about it. I agree, it might not be the most obviously implementation.

Comment: I agree it's not, hence the question. Thanks for the explanation. But do you think it would be a good idea to file a feature request for this?

Comment: Might as well! Nothing wrong with a bit of constructive criticism from the users.